# Android Expo app crashing on launch due to invalid Firebase API key

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm building a React Native app using Expo and Firebase.
It is working fine in development, but crashes while launching on my android device.
I used the command 'adb logcat' to detect errors, and got the following error on lauching my app:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).

**What is causing this?** The previous version of my app worked properly on android phones and did not encounter this error. However, in the current version (which is crashing) I have introduced user authentication (ie the ability for users to create accounts and log in/ log off). Maybe this has introduced the error?

In the 'Project Settings' tab of my firebase project, there are two different APIs listed:
A 'Web API Key' listed under the 'Your project' header, and the 'apiKey' listed in the 'firebaseConfig' object.
The 'firebaseConfig' API key is used in my 'firebase.js' configuration, however the 'Web API Key' is used in my 'google-services.json' file:

**firebase.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"
import Constants from 'expo-constants'


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: Constants.manifest?.extra?.firebaseApiKey,
  authDomain: "gig-fort-f8a59.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "gig-fort-f8a59",
  storageBucket: "gig-fort-f8a59.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "595475966846",
  appId: "1:5954***",
  measurementId: "G-VD3XDEQRXH"
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app)
export const auth = getAuth(app)
```

**google-services.json**

```
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "[Web Api Key]"
        }
```

This is how I've configured my **app.config.json** file:

```
    extra: {
      firebaseApiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
      eas: {
        projectId: "b4ab63***",
      },
    },
```

The API_KEY value in my 'GoogleService-Info.plist' is something different altogether.
I've also checked my '.env' file, and the API key matches the SDK config key.
I'm wondering if I've got the wrong API key somewhere, or if I missed a step when setting up authentication for my app.